# Is there a Riemann Hypothesis criterion utilizing sum of squares of divisors?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis, divisors-multiples

Robin's inequality
$$\sigma_1(n)<e^\gamma n\log\log n$$
at integers $n>5040$ provides necessary and sufficient condition for Riemann Hypothesis where $\sigma_1(n)=\sum_{d|n}d$ is sum of divisors function applied to integer $n$.

Is there a necessary and sufficient condition involving sum of squares of divisors function $\sigma_2(n)=\sum_{d|n}d^2$?

Comment: Can you use the fact that $\sigma_2(n)\le (\sigma_1(n))^2$?

Comment: Do not think $\leq$ guarantees $\iff$. Is there a magic the cross-terms provide?

Comment: No but perhaps you can get $\ge$ using Cauchy's inequality.

Comment: ...or, perhaps the simple $\sigma_1\le \sigma_2$ is enough.

Comment: ... I mean $\sigma_2(n)<e^{2\gamma} n^2(\log\log n)^2$ could be equivalent to RH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect no: the big difference between $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_k$ for
$k\ge2$ is that in the latter case $\sigma_k(n)/n^k$ is trivially bounded by
$\zeta(k)$, which doesn't leave much room for a Robin type criterion.

Comment: @1.. That inequality indeed implies failure of RH. It implies a lot of things, since it is straight up false (for large $n$) - we have $\sigma_2(n)<\zeta(2)n^2$.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes I corrected my mistake. $\sigma_2(n)<\zeta(2)n^2\implies\sigma_2(n)<e^{2\gamma}n^2(\log\log n)^2$ holds.

Comment: @HenriCohen can we replace $2$ by $1+\epsilon$ at any $\epsilon>0$?